# Adding a static IP to a Azure Service Bus endpoint

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-virtual-network

Due to a strict firewall policy we are looking to make our Service Bus endpoint have a static IP address.

I have tried the following:

1. Created a Reserved IP using the Classic Deployment Model in powershell

I encountered this issue: [Why does New-AzureReservedIP return ResourceNotFound: No deployments were found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077602/why-does-new-azurereservedip-return-resourcenotfound-no-deployments-were-found)
Unfortunately, the solution did not resolve my issue.

2. Created a Public IP in resource manager.

This came to a dead-end as I was not able add the Service Bus to the VNET.

---

Has anyone had any success creating a static IP for a service bus endpoint?

Are there any solutions to the issues I encountered with the reservedip/publicip methods I tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Bus is a multi-tenant service, like SQL Database, DocumentDB, etc. You cannot choose the endpoint's IP address. You simply access the endpoint via your chosen namespace (e.g. `sb://yournamespace.servicebus.windows.net`).

From a security standpoint, Service Bus does support Shared Access Signatures (similar to Azure Storage).